# Can i use an ng-include in my <html> tag

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to alter my whole html page to dynamically change to a new one, can i feel putting the ng-include in  tag will make the whole content of the page change dynamically. Is this possible.

Comment: Please post some example code :)